# CRUD method doesn`t use the hsql-db connection?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, crud, hsqldb

i am currently coding a CRUD Program and I am using hsql-db:

Here is my hsql-db connector class:

```
public class hsqlmanager {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(hsqlmanager.class);

    private static Connection con=null;

    private static void openConnection(){
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" );
            log.info("Loaded JDBC Driver");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ERROR: failed to load JDBC driver - " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db_test","SA","");
            log.info("Connection established");         
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            log.error("db connection error Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void closeConnection() {
        try {
            con.close();
            log.info("DB conn closed");
        }
        catch(SQLException e) {
            log.error("Error at closing" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (con==null){
            openConnection();
        }
        else {
            try {
                if(con.isClosed()){
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db_test","SA","");
                    log.info("DB connection re-opened.");
                }
            } catch(SQLException e){
                log.error("re-open mistake" + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        return con;
    }

}
```

Here is my crud class:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class DAOProdukt implements IDAOProdukt {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DAOProdukt.class);
    Connection conn;

    public DAOProdukt(){
        conn = hsqlmanager.getConnection();
    }
    //created ein Produkt p
    @Override
    public void create(Produkt p) {
        if(p==null) {           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Erstellen von null-Objekten in der DB nicht möglich");
        }
        PreparedStatement ps=null;

        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Produkt(name, kategorie, delete) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);");
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            log.error("Cannot establish db connection");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            ps.setString(1, p.getName());
            ps.setString(2, p.getKategorie());
            ps.setBoolean(3, p.isDeleted());
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();

            log.info("Produkt created.");
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            log.error("Produkt couldn`t be created: " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

the compiler always points to the crud class and gives me the error message:

```
log.error("Cannot establish db connection");
```

I very much appreciate your answer!!!

PS.: I run the server with that command:
java -classpath lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:hsqldb/hemrajdb --dbname.0 db_test

Answer (score 0):

You must start the HSQLDB server to serve the database at the `jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db_test` URL before attempting to connect.

See the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_server_modes

You comment that you have started the server. I therefore looked more closely at your code. There is a problem here:

```
    try {
        ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Produkt(name, kategorie, delete) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);");
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        log.error("Cannot establish db connection");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When you catch the exception, you should log the exception message. The fixed message you log can be incorrect.

If you look at the INSERT statement, there are three columns listed, but four parameters as values. HSQLDB will throw an exception with an informative message. But your code ignores the message and prints your own, incorrect message instead.

Comment: ok I tried to refactor the code a little bit and put the jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db_test first, but I stil get the same error message...

Comment: The server is a separate process which you run before your program.

Comment: yeah my server is running with that command: java -classpath lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server --database.0 file:hsqldb/hemrajdb --dbname.0 db_test